# How to rename download file in php or in any language

Tags: php, html, web-services

Can someone explain me about this url?

`https://dropmb.com/files/1556342ef5911342c170809809cc3f9d.rar`

It will download as 'SM-G532G 7.0 S.BOOT WWW.FIXFIRMWARES.COM.rar' in my computer.

How can i do that in my website.
The link above is a direct link. right?
Why the file name is not "1556342ef5911342c170809809cc3f9d.rar" instead "SM-G532G 7.0 S.BOOT WWW.FIXFIRMWARES.COM.rar" upon download.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by specifying in the [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition).

Example

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"
```